# Sorting a list of lists in Prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, backtracking

I have a school project where I have to take people and seat them according to dining preferences. For example, say I have the following people:

Bob: Likes foods A,B,C,D,E

Carol: Likes foods B,E,D,C,A

Ronald: Likes foods E,A,C,B,D

Stacy: Likes foods A,E,B,D,C

The order of foods corresponds their preferences, the first food being their most favorite, last being least. The ideal order would be Bob, Stacy, Carol, Ronald. It pairs the people who share the favorite food and seats the rest in alphabetical order according to preference.

My method for solving this was assigning letters A-E to numbers 1-5. From there, I wanted to build a list of lists which contained the numbers corresponding to the food. From there I would sort the list according to the logic that it compares the first elements of each sublist, and if they are the same to compare the second and so forth elements.

I am getting stuck at building the master list of lists though. How would I go about doing this? Or is there a better method to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you talk about sorting in CS, the math topic in play is *total ordering*. One important thing about a total ordering is that it is *transitive*, and I have a lump in my stomach about your description that maybe this is not a total ordering. After all, suppose we have four people: Alice, Bob, Cindy and Dave. Alice's food preferences might be A,B,C,D and Bob's B,C,D,A and Cindy's C,D,A,B and Dave's D,A,B,C. While it's clear that Alice and Cindy are further from each other, there's no obvious way to choose between pairing Alice with Bob or Dave. And all four people have the same problem: there are always two people they are equally close to. Does the algorithm generate Alice&Bob and Cindy&Dave or Dave&Alice and Bob&Cindy? (Incidentally, the same problem arises for the same reason in voting systems; this is the lack of a [Condorcet winner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_method).)

Now, the nice thing about Prolog is that you can come up with an algorithm that generates multiple solutions. So in this case, it would generate both solutions: the one with Alice&Bob and the one with Alice&Dave. But a list can only be sorted according to some criterion one way, so it doesn't feel like sorting a master list is going to be part of it. I feel like, because there will often be multiple solutions, you probably do not have the right approach. And the right one with Prolog would probably be to take the first person in the list and find the next-best match, recursively. Assuming you code it right, if there are two with the same "distance" you should generate both.

**Edit**: incidentally, I thought of another example: [sorting color](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87588/how-to-sort-colors-properly).